# Session information not passed in RSpec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

when trying to write some controller specs testing my routes setup I'running into problems when trying to pass session information with session hash being empty (`session == {}`).

The relevant part of `routes.rb` has the following constraint I want to test:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'places/review_index', constraints: MapOwnershipRestriction.new, to:  'review#review_index', as: :review_index
  ...
end
```

`MapOwnershipRestriction` looks like this

```
 class MapOwnershipRestriction
    def matches?(request)     
      token = request[:map_token]
      map = Map.find_by(secret_token: token)
      user = User.find_by(id: request.session[:user_id])
      map.user == user ? true : false 
    end                       
  end
```

Now, the following (example) test fails due to non-existing session information since `request.session[:user_id]` is empty:

```
      it 'populates the right place to be reviewed' do
~       @user = create :user
~       @map = create :map, :full_public, user: @user
~       @new_place = create :place, :unreviewed, name: 'SomeName', map: @map 
~       session[:user_id] = @user.id
+       expect(get: review_place_path(id: @new_place.id, map_token: @map.secret_token)).to be_routable
      end
```

All articles and SO Q&As did not help me so far.

best and thx in advance,
Andi

Comment: Don't use controller specs to test your routes in the first place.  `ActionController::TestCase` (which controller specs are just a veneer on top of) fakes the whole step of performing an actual HTTP request by creating a mocked request object. What that means is that the routing component in rails is never actually used - `ActionController::TestCase` just checks if there is a route that that looks kind of right in the routes definition and raises an error if it can't find one with the right signature.

Comment: What you want to use instead is a [*request spec*](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) which actually creates a http request that hits the rails stack. Its also more future proof as controller tests are depreciated in Rails 5.

Comment: hey max, thx a lot, gonna try this out